# Refuse any push to origin which contains changes outside certain files

Tags: ruby, git, github, githooks, github-api

I am managing a repo of student work.  Students have access to each others work, but should only make changes within their own folders in the repo.  I am looking to write a githook, preferably in ruby, that will refuse any pushes to the remote origin repo that contain changes outside their own files.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  I'm finding that documentation is relatively sparse when it comes to this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: hows about making them do pull requests? :)

Comment: That is part of the current procedure.  I'm looking to avoid manually processing pull requests.

Comment: oh, cool, smart decision! hope it works out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment about avoiding manually processing pull requests, I think this might be an approach you could use:

1. You set up the repository where each student has a folder to work in.
2. You [create a web hook](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook) for that repository which is triggered by [pull_request events](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#events). See below for an explanation of what the hook does.
3. Students have only read access to the repository, so each student has to fork the repository.
4. A student makes changes to some files in their fork.
5. The student submits a pull request to your fork.
6. Your hook is triggered by the pull request event. Using the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files), the hook lists all the files in the pull request and verifies that the user who made the pull request is allowed to modify those files.
7. If the user modified only files that they were allowed to, the pull request is merged by the hook via [another API call](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-buttontrade). However, if the user modified files that they shouldn't have -- then the pull request is closed via [a different API call](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request). You could also [automatically create a comment](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment) on the pull request to explain why it was closed.

The hook could be implemented in any language, as long as it is able to receive a POST request with the pull_request event. You could deploy it to Heroku, for example.